# Simultaneous AJAX requests causes PHP Session not to be updated properly

Tags: php, ajax, session, extjs

In my application I have an AJAX request that runs every 10 seconds, which tells the server that the user is still connected. When a user does an action another AJAX request is sent to the server which increments a number in the PHP $_SESSION variable.

I seem to be getting problems when these two AJAX requests happen at exactly the same time - the number in the $_SESSION is not incremented sometimes. I believe this is because when the two requests run at the same time, sometimes the one that increments the $_SESSION variable finishes before the other request, and so last request 'overwrites' the session with the old data. Has anyone else had this problem or know how to solve it?

Comment: can you share the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by my custom session handler (using session_set_save_handler), which was saving session information into an Oracle database. It had nothing in it which stopped two simultaneous scripts modifying the session. Therefore, to stop this happening, I added a file-based lock using flock() to the session 'read' handler. The file is then deleted and the lock removed in the 'destroy' handler.

This fixed the problem, but now means that AJAX requests seem to have to run sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to set the timeout for the next 10 seconds when the current ajax request has finished processing. So don't use an interval, set a timeout on completion.